# adding a click event to confirm image color javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was writing a javascript game so that everytime 4 different random colors are placed on the screen as images and the player is asked to click on the green color, however I cant find what to write on the click function even after searching so much, also how to I make the images keep changing automatically every few say for example 2 seconds

heres how the game works : 
when the page loads, 4 blank white images are shown
after clicking on the start button 4 different colors take place of the blank image
after clicking on the green image the game should say alert something

I used 0-5 code for colors on the script for img src  0.jpg being for white , 1-4 green red blue brown respectively

any help would be appreciated

the code : http://jsfiddle.net/gf2un/1/

### JS

```
var counter = 0;
var greenNumber;

function start() {
    var button = document.getElementById("startButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", generateColor, false);
}

function generateColor() {
    var color;
    var imgCheck = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {

        do
        color = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
        while (imgCheck.indexOf(color) !== -1)
        if (color == 1) greenNumber = i;
        imgCheck[i] = color;

        setImage(i, color);
    }
}

function setImage(rdmNumber, color) {
    var rdmImg = document.getElementById("color" + rdmNumber);
    rdmImg.setAttribute("src", "images//" + color + ".jpg");
    rdmImg.setAttribute("width", "90px");
}

function Click( clickedImage )
{
var theSrc = clickedImage.src;
    if (theSrc = "image/1.jpg")
++counter;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score : " + counter;
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

### HTML

```
<center>
    <p>CLICK ON THE GREEN SQUARE</p>
    <p>
    <img id = "color4" src = "images/0.jpg" alt = "box 1 image" width = "90px" onClick = "Click(this)">
    <img id = "color1" src = "images/0.jpg" alt = "box 2 image" width = "90px" onClick = "Click(this)">
    </p>
    <p>
    <img id = "color2" src = "images/0.jpg" alt = "box 3 image" width = "90px" onClick = "Click(this)">
    <img id = "color3" src = "images/0.jpg" alt = "box 4 image" width = "90px" onClick = "Click(this)">
    </p>

    <form action = "#">
        <input id = "startButton" type = "button" value = "Start">
    </form>

    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it too complex; you don't need to create *REAL* images. Instead, play with the css a little. It makes the code look more neat, and the player doesn't require to download the images.

Shuffling is easy, when you are using a container.

Add *click* functions with method `addEventListener()`. This **adds** an event to the HTML object, so you can add more than one function to it.

Here's my **working** version of your game: **http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/k3J9b/1/** Try it! No seriously, i made this game for you! Inspect it, copy it or use it fully, it's all yours! I also added lots of comments for you.

**Shuffle example:**

```
//    changes the color and shuffles the deck.
function newColor() {
    //    we change the color we want the user to press.
    var rand_color       =    randomValue(colors);
    curColor.innerHTML   =    rand_color;
    //    we also change the color of the span, so it changes the text color.
    curColor.style.color =    rand_color;

    //    we shuffle constant SHUFFLE_MAX times and re-add it to the container.
    for (var i=0; i<SHUFFLE_MAX; i++) {
        container.appendChild( randomValue(boxes) );
    }
}
```

**returns a random value in the array:**

```
function randomValue(array) {
    return array[(Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length))];
}
```

Comment: i never knew you could do those with css, ty for your time on writing the code i will try to understand it and make a mobile version of it too :P